# Machine model for primitive recursion?

Tags: computability-theory

General computable functions can be described either functionally (in terms of closure of
the coordinate functions, constant functions, composition, primitive recursion, and $\mu$-recursion), or in terms of a Turing machine.

I have only seen primitive recursion defined in the functional language, i.e. functions obtained by coordinates, constants, composition, primitive recursion.

Is there a similar type of machine model for primitive recursion?

I am aware of some (pedagogical) programming languages, such as Hofstadter's BLOOP, that are PR-complete, but this approach doesn't really look like a Turing machine to me.

Comment: There is very little you can do with Turing machines except imposing resource bounds (time and/or space). A function is PR iff it is computable on a TM in time (or space) $O(A(c,n))$ for some constant $c$, where $A$ is Ackermann function, which is not a particularly elegant characterization. I’m not familiar with BLOOP, but what’s wrong with it? I would naturally go for a minimalistic programming language-like model rather than TM when asked to give a computational model exhausting primitive recursive functions.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a *machine model*?  Such formulations are beneficial mostly for philosophical reasons.  For example, the advantage of the Turing-machine formulation of the Entscheidungsproblem is that it focuses all of the "infiniteness" in one place: the tape; everything else about the machine is finite.  This laid to rest a lot of philosophical uncertainties in the 1930s about the role of the infinite ${\mathbb N}$ in $\mu$-recursion and insertion of characters into unboundedly-long $\lambda$-terms.  I'm not sure there's any reason to prefer a machine model now that...

Comment: ... Turing has established that the notion of computability does not rely on anything mysterious about the "less disciplined infiniteness" of the other formulations.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to accept [register machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_machine) (rather than just tape machines), you can get what you want via the [Grzegorczyk hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grzegorczyk_hierarchy), which generates the class of primitive recursive functions in stages.

The ${n+1}^{th}$ stage of the hierarchy ${\mathscr E}_{n+1}$ is the closure of the zero, successor, projection, and  [hyper operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_operation) $H_n$ function under composition and *bounded recursion*.

Bounded recursion is defined just like primitive recursion, except that when defining a function $f$ at the ${n+1}^{th}$ level, the definitions of the base case and inductive case for $f(m,\bar x)$ must take the form $\text{min}(g(m,\bar x),...)$ where $g$ is a function from the $n^{th}$ level.

Every primitive recursive function belongs to ${\mathscr E}_n$ for some $n$, and every function in the hierarchy is primitive recursive.

Beltiukov's [stack register machines](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/997df5ff55640141a337239e0c83e37c/znsl_3100_card_eng.pdf) (also [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/r0h6nw66t123l5g6/fulltext.pdf)) give a "machine-oriented" characterization of the Grzegorczyk hierarchy -- and therefore of the primitive recursive functions.  There is a slightly more accessible description of stack register machines [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/f74740307h6x3880/fulltext.pdf), starting on page 108.

Comment: The perhaps slightly more accessible equivalent answer is a C program with bigints and unlimited memory using only "for" loops with bounded integer limits, and no recursive function calls.

Comment: @Ron: This is not equivalent since C rules for 'for' loops are much too relaxed. For example, for (i=1; i<10; i++) i--; is a perfectly legal non-terminating program according to your restrictions.

Comment: The links to `springerlink.com` are broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshots saved on the Wayback Machine.